# Left-invariant Riemannian metric on $SO(3)$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, orthonormal

Let's consier the manifold $SO(3)$. First problem is to show that $T_I SO(3)$ is a space of skew-symmetric matrices $3\times 3$. How can I deduce it?
Then I have to prove there exists exactly one left-invariant Riemannian metric such that matrices
$$
A_1 = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
\quad
A_2 = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
\quad
A_3 = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)
$$ 
are the orthonormal basis of $T_I SO(3)$. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINTS**: Consider the function $f(A) = A^\top A$ on the space of $3\times 3$ matrices. Compute $df_I(B)$ and see what it means for this to be $0$.

Next: If you define an orthonormal basis for $T_ISO(3)$, then left-translating it everywhere will give you an orthonormal basis at $T_ASO(3)$ for all $A\in SO(3)$. Does this determine a unique Riemannian metric on $SO(3)$?

Comment: Thanks, now I see. So matrices $A_i$ induce an orthonormal basis at every point of $SO(3)$. What do I need to compute the Levi-Civita connection in this basis? Should I have some local charts?

Comment: No, you don't want to use charts. How do you usually work with the Levi-Civita connection? Do you use differential forms or vector fields? Either way, the structure constants of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ are going to show up here.